# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

i tried to run an sql code (shown below) and this wont work, i get an error for the 'CREATE TABLE' line: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

the code is as follows:

```
con = lite.connect('Records.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Progress(Id INTEGER PRIMARY, Username STRING, Topic1 STRING, Topic2 STRING, Topic3 STRING, Topic4 STRING, 1Result STRING, 2Result STRING, 3Result STRING, 4Result STRING, TResut STRING, TCorrect INTEGER, TWrong INTEGER, TAttempted INTEGER)")
    cur.exectue("INSERT INTO Progress VALUES(1, 'Admin', 'Algebra', 'Number', 'Shape, Space and Measures', 'Handling Data', '100%', '100%', '100%', '100%', '100%', 10, 0, 10)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two kinds of errors:

1. Replace `INTEGER PRIMARY` with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. This is what causes the error message you're seeing.
2. After fixing that, rename identifiers starting with a number with something starting with a letter. For example, rename `1Result` to e.g. `Result1`.